# Vue passing data to POST method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a problem with passing data to Vuejs `post` method. I'm using vue-resource and in documentation is:

```
this.$http.post('/someUrl', [body], [options]).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

I want to put header and it works fine(server reads header correct) for:

```
 this.$http.post(
      'http://localhost:8081/login', 
      {
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
      });
```

but if I try add any data something goes wrong, for example I tried:

```
this.$http.post(
      'http://localhost:8081/login',
       {username: 'admin'},
      {
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
      });
```

or define some data and put there like:

```
this.$http.post(
      'http://localhost:8081/login', 
       this.data,
      {
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
      });
```

and for both solutions body section is always empty - check body data from request by using:

```
 body = req.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
```

Probably problem is in vue.js code ebcause it works fine it I send any request from Postman. What should I do?

Comment: Use Axios, Vue Resource is not maintained anymore and not fully compatible with Vue 2

Comment: It is very easy to blame a tool :) I think there is even a saying about that. Tell me what error are you getting. "It's not working is hardly enough data". Even though @BelminBedak is right about VueResource I had no problem using it and I don't plan to stop.

Comment: @peaceman I used Vue Resource on VueJS 2 Based project and it worked fine for me too - I only dealed with GET Requests.It's suggested by community to use Axios.I don't blame the tool, I just say what is recommended.

Comment: @BelminBedak , no the comment wasn't directed towards you nor was it a criticism. I've also read stuff online before using it and axios does seem like a great choice, in addition to that vue and vue-resource groups have parted ways. That enabled vue to be used with any other solution for server communication. All that being said VueResource is still a reasonable choice and it does most anything you need ( well get and post... I didn't work with other verbs :) )

Comment: @peaceman just my request body is always empty and in general my methods doesn't work like in Postman. Could you put there example with some values in header and some data in body? (I tried a lot of things but still nothing)

Comment: "A poor craftsman blame's his tools"

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried sending a post request without including the third argument with post

```
this.$http.post('url', {something: "string"})
  .then ((res)=> console.log (res.body))
  .catch ((error)=> console.log(error))
```

This works for me...

Another thing, are you sure you're getting the request data properly in the back end... it seems like python and I'm not totally sure how it works.

Comment: it's Spring-boot and for your code body is `""`.. I dont know what is wrong because if I use Postman everything works well...

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't help you with Java&spring but I can assure you that VueResource part is working because I've done in on numerous occasions. You are posting a valid json data. You can either try playing with axious or jquery Ajax to be sure, or play with your backend code to see if there is something happening there. Is that the only way to print request data?

Comment: I tried jquery but there is the same problem (body is empty). Do u have any idea why request from bowse is different from request from Postman?

Comment: It could be a number of things... I'm not knowledgeable enough to give you a list :) I would try either $("#form-selector").serialize() and send that or var formData = new FormData() and then use formData.append("key", "value") and send formData as data object. Let me know if it works or not :) sry I can't be of any help

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example if you want to send multiple JSON values.

```js
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    email: '',
    password: ''
  },
  methods: {
    getPosts() {
      return axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/login',
        { email: this.email,
          password: this.password
        },
        { headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        }
      }).then((response) => {
        console.log('email: ' + this.email);
        console.log('password: ' + this.password);
      }).catch( error => { 
        console.log('error: ' + error); 
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="email" name="email" v-model="email">
  <input type="password" name="password" v-model="password">
  <button v-on:click="getPosts()">Login</button>
</div>
```